# Animation Choppy

Tags: animation

Last night my animation was working just fine and then this morning it started to play every frame individually very slowly which made it very choppy and slow. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: May be something caused a framedrop. In most of the cases it helps a lot if you hide the graph editor or the dopesheet while playing the animation.

Comment: It's still being choppy. Could it be something with my computer? I also realized that when I was trying to weight paint on my mesh it was being very slow too.

Comment: I tried restarting and checking the computer for updates so know it seems like everything else is faster but blender is still being slow.

Comment: here is a link to the animation recorded:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dsf2Acww-M1zMMi_SV1AJmWp9eupkYFq/view

Comment: Although its not a solution, if you want to easily view an animation at normal speed that cannot play back at the speed, you can go to the top bar in the viewport, press view, and viewport render animation.

Comment: You have 2 fps, as you can see in the top left corner in the 3d view. Try to check what leaks your sources in the task manager or try to reset the settings in the preferences.

Comment: how do you check what leaks your sources?

Comment: I got rid of my subdivision subsurface and it worked just fine. Any idea how I could re-add the subdivision subsurface without it slowing it down?